# Dotnet c# 8.0 connecting to Mysql

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to connect a simple demo app to a mysql docker container. The version of Mysql is 8.2.0. C# is 8.0. I created a webapi project in VS 2022 17.8.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

        //add mysql dbcontext
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<NamesContext>(options =>
        
            options.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 2, 0)))); // replace with your server version

        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        var summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", (HttpContext httpContext) =>
        {
            var forecast = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
                new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray();
            return forecast;
        })
        .WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
        .WithOpenApi();



        //add endpoint to access Names
        
        app.MapGet("/names", async (HttpContext httpContext) =>
        {
            using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<NamesContext>();
            var names = await context.Names.Select(n => n.Name).ToListAsync();
            return names;
        });

        

        app.Run();
    }
}

public class NamesContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Names> Names { get; set; }

    public NamesContext(DbContextOptions<NamesContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Names>().ToTable("Names", "db1");
    }
}

public class Names
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

My nugets are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="8.0.0">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; 
     buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.23" />
<PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
```

The error I am getting is

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'. at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlBoolTypeMapping..ctor(String storeType, Nullable`1 dbType, Nullable`1 size)
> at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlTypeMappingSource..ctor(TypeMappingSourceDependencies dependencies, RelationalTypeMappingSourceDependencies relationalDependencies, IMySqlOptions options)

I have not worked with Pomelo before and not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

I am just trying to set up the correct access to the docker data in the docker (I don't believe docker is even a factor here).  The table just has Id and Name is a table called db1 (maybe that is my issue but I added the OnModelCreating).

Suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use the prerelease version of Pomelo (8.0.0-beta.2)

Comment: Can you add that as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use the prerelease version of Pomelo (8.0.0-beta.2)